# Mom and dad having different mailing addresses. B2 Visitor Visa

Tags: b1-b2-visas

My mom and dad have different addresses in their respective passports. They are their respective work places and usually my dad travels to my mom's place every weekend. Is it ok if they have different addresses in their DS-160?

Comment: About half my friends have divorced parents. Just because they are your mother and father don’t mean they’re married to each other or that they cohabitate.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be okay? Your mother and father may even have different familes, that would also be no problem.

Comment: OP has not returned to answer clarifications/questions from comments. Put on hold for now.